# How do i convert a JArray[String] to Scala List

Tags: json, scala, json4s

I am struggling to convert a Jarray[JString] to  Scala List[String]

```
scala> (configMap \ "orderedCols").extract[JArray]
  res27: org.json4s.JArray = JArray(List(JString(id), JString(name)))

 scala> (configMap \ "orderedCols").extract[JArray].toList
 <console>:40: error: value toList is not a member of org.json4s.JArray
   (configMap \ "orderedCols").extract[JArray].toList
```

Can someone help me
^
Expected output : List("id","name")

Comment: To take a `List` from `JArray` you should use `arr`. 
(you can find some examples [here](https://json4s.org/))

Comment: ok. I will try this

Comment: BEWARE: Json4s is [vulnerable under DoS/DoW attacks](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+denial)!